# Problem with Jboss EAP 7 server.log and application log

Tags: jboss, log4j, stack-trace, jboss-eap-7

i have the following problem with jboss log and my application log. Some errors are write in server log in this way

```
15:46:16,834 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-41) UT005023: Exception handling request to /fnsuap/cmd/home: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.LockTimeoutException: Unable to acquire conversation lock after 30 seconds
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
....
```

And then are write in my application log in this way:

```
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.LockTimeoutException: Unable to acquire conversation lock after 30 seconds
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
[09/06/20 03:46:15:015 CEST] ERROR stderr:  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
...
```

So is like every line of stacktrace is a new error.
Why this happens? How can i solve this?

Use log4j1.2

Comment: Any messages coming from the server itself will not print to the applications log. There is a bit of detail about it in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-4807.

Comment: Ok, if this is true, why application log intercept also this log?

Comment: I'm not too sure really. It could be one is coming from the server and one is coming from the Spring.